# Is there an option in VSCode to show the matching line brace opening line as a hint when the mouse or cursor is on closing brace or line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an option to show what line a closing brace relates to when hovering over that closing brace in VSCode?

For example, if you have an if statement and the opening brace is off screen can vscode show the opening line?

```
if (red) {  

   if (blue {

       if (yellow) {

           if (green) {



           }
       }
   }| "if (blue) {"
}
```

If the cursor or mouse is on the second to last closing brace it shows the hint:

`if (blue) {`

If the cursor or mouse is on the last closing brace it shows the hint:

`if (red) {`

Does this make sense? Is this an existing feature?

Comment: if not already implemented you can write an extension with a `HoverProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rainbow Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets) offered a similar functionality and is now baked into VS Code. Search for the settings `@id:editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled @id:editor.guides.bracketPairs` and set

- `Bracket Pair Colorization` to `Enabled` and
- `Bracket Pairs` to `true`

Comment: Fantastic! Nice addition